# Hitting "Filter Chain Unauthorized" during POST request, in React / Ruby on Rails Feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, devise, axios

First stack overflow question, so I apologize ahead of time for forgetting things.

Project:

- Announcement Feature, which allows admin / moderators to post announcements on website.

Tools/Languages Used:

- React / Ruby on Rails, Devise (for login)

History:

- The announcement feature was UP and RUNNING; until I added a "Username" field to my Announcement table. I properly updated the migration/schema, and made adjustments to the controller, to permit the new field, as well as the React form, to pass the new field into the announcements object.

Error:

- After updating migration/schema files with new fields, updating announcement_controller to permit the new field, and updating the React form to capture and POST the new "Announcement" object through an AXIOS POST request, I get the following error: "Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected" 401 unauthorized, etc.

Things I've Tried So Far:

- I've verified all the data the SHOULD be in the announcement object, just before being pushed through the POST request, is where it should be. (See images below)
- I tried using a Binding.Pry, which works like Javascript's "Debugger" except for Ruby, but my binding.pry wasn't stopping ANYWHERE in the announcements controller, which leads me to believe the POST request isn't even making it to the announcements_controller before the error below.
- I've verified the Announcements table is what it should be.
- I've set the new field to to be permitted in the announcement_controller

Code Examples / Images:

handleSubmit POST request

```
  handleSubmit = (announcement) => { axios.post(`/api/announcements`, announcement)}
```

[Contents of "announcement" JUST before being passed into handleSubmit()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAfqj.png)

[Filter Chain Halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirect: Error Message AFTER POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXLA3.png)

[Announcements schema / database / table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ARsf.png)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_12_19_224825) do

```
    # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this 
  database
    enable_extension "plpgsql"

    create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "account_name"
      t.bigint "users_id"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_users_id"
    end

    create_table "announcements", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "body"
      t.bigint "user_id"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_announcements_on_user_id"
    end

    create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "game_name"
      t.bigint "accounts_id"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.index ["accounts_id"], name: "index_games_on_accounts_id"
    end

    create_table "team_has_tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.bigint "tournament_id"
      t.bigint "team_id"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_team_has_tournaments_on_team_id"
      t.index ["tournament_id"], name: "index_team_has_tournaments_on_tournament_id"
    end

    create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "team_name"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

    create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.text "tournament_description"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.string "tournament_name"
    end

    create_table "user_has_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.bigint "user_id"
      t.bigint "team_id"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_user_has_teams_on_team_id"
      t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_has_teams_on_user_id"
    end

    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "provider", default: "email", null: false
      t.string "uid", default: "", null: false
      t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
      t.string "reset_password_token"
      t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
      t.boolean "allow_password_change", default: false
      t.datetime "remember_created_at"
      t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
      t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
      t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
      t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
      t.string "confirmation_token"
      t.datetime "confirmed_at"
      t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
      t.string "unconfirmed_email"
      t.string "firstName"
      t.string "lastName"
      t.string "username"
      t.string "image"
      t.string "email"
      t.json "tokens"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.integer "level", default: 1
      t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
      t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
      t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
      t.index ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true
    end

    add_foreign_key "accounts", "users", column: "users_id"
    add_foreign_key "announcements", "users"
    add_foreign_key "games", "accounts", column: "accounts_id"
    add_foreign_key "team_has_tournaments", "teams"
    add_foreign_key "team_has_tournaments", "tournaments"
    add_foreign_key "user_has_teams", "teams"
    add_foreign_key "user_has_teams", "users"
  end
```

[Announcements controller that should be handling POST request (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLD7x.png)

[Announcements controller that should be handling POST request (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgKp.png)

```
    class Api::AnnouncementsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_announcement, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      render json: Announcement.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
      render json: @announcement
    end


    def new
      @announcement = Announcement.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
      announcement = Announcement.new(announcement_params)

      if announcement.save
        render json: build_announcement(announcement)
      else
        render json: announcement.errors, status: 422
      end
    end

    def update
      if @announcement.update(announcement_params)
        render json: @announcement
      else
        render json: @announcement.errors, status: 422
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @announcement.destroy
    end

    private

    def build_announcement(announcement)
      {
        id: announcement.id,
        body: announcement.body,
        username: announcement.username,
        user_id: announcement.user_id,
        created_at: announcement.created_at,
        updated_at: announcement.updated_at,
      }
    end

    def set_announcement
      @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:id])
    end

    def announcement_params
      params.require(:announcement).permit(:body, :username, :user_id)
    end
    end
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to replace all the images with the actual text? Images can be difficult to view on some devices. And, images make it impossible to copy code into answers in which case you are asking us to view all your images, find potential problems, generate potential solutions, and retype corrected code in our answers. Which is not all that much fun.

Comment: I'd be happy to! I'm still new at this. When I tried the first time (to put just the code in) it didn't seem to recognize it as actual code. Maybe because it was Ruby, I'm not sure. Suggestions, so that the indentation/highlighting is maintained? I'll fiddle with it in the meanwhile.

Comment: Your `binding.pry` is never reached because of the halt that's happening. The `authenticate_user!` is returning the `401`, hence you'll never get to your `pry.` In short, it looks like you're not logged in.

Comment: @jvillian Unfortunately, I've closed/repoened the terminal since then. Copy/pasting the terminal output wouldn't help debug the issues anyway. A more productive approach would be to read over the information and add suggestions based on your own experience.

Comment: @fanta You're right, I came to that same conclusion. On refresh, I'm redirected to login. My confusion is WHY the halt is happening to begin with. It's a head-scratcher. Whats worse is that when I came back from lunch and tried it again, it was working PERFECTLY fine, without any changes on my part. I still think it would be beneficial to leave the post up for the sake of anyone that might have an explanation as to why its happening in the first place, especially considering the actual problem was never figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I note that your console output includes:

```
User Load (50.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["uid", "admin@admin.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

(notwithstanding any typing errors on my part.)

It appears that you are trying to find the user with a `uid` of `admin@admin.com`. In your comments (deleted now, I think), you had said that you don't have such a user. If that's the case, then I assume that is what's causing your:

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
```

I think I would start with researching that bit.

Comment: That makes sense. Although it doesn’t stand as an answer to the problem itself. Why would it would try that SELECT statement to begin with? I mentioned in the comments above, after getting back from lunch, the POST request started working just fine without me having to make any edits. As far as I know, the SQL side of things is handled by the Axios/Rails/whatever handles that.